# How do I put a checkbox in the title/label of a Dojo TabContainer?

Tags: checkbox, dojo

I want to put a checkbox in the label of a Dojo TabContainer. I found an example here:

http://telliott.net/dojoExamples/dojo-checkboxTabExample.html

However, the example only shows html. I would like to do this programmatically. This is what I have so far:

```
function(response){
    var json_response = JSON.parse(response);
    var fields_dict = json_response['fields_dict'];
    var names_dict = json_response['names_dict'];
    var tc = new TabContainer({
        style: "height: 495px; width: 100%;",
        tabPosition: "left",
        tabStrip: true
    }, "report_tab_container");
    for(var key in fields_dict) {
        var content_string = '';
        var fields = fields_dict[key];
        for(var field in fields) content_string += '<div>' + fields[field][0] + fields[field][1] + '</div>';
        var checkBox = new CheckBox({
            name: "checkBox",
            value: "agreed",
            checked: false,
            onChange: function(b){ alert('onChange called with parameter = ' + b + ', and widget value = ' + this.get('value') ); }
        }).startup();
        var tcp = new ContentPane({
            //title: names_dict[key],
            title: checkBox,
            content: content_string
        });

        tc.addChild(tcp);
    }

    tc.startup();
    tc.resize();
},
```

However, this doesn't work. When I load my page, the TabContainer doesn't show up. If I set the title of my ContentPane to something other than my check box, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong and how do I get the checkbox to appear in the TabContainer title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked:

```
cb.placeAt('report_tab_container_tablist_dijit_layout_ContentPane_'+ i.toString(), "first");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this blindly here, but comparing the example on your link to your code, I would say, add this before tc.addChild(tcp) :

```
checkBox.placeAt(tcp.domNode, "first");
```

Comment: That didn't work. The CheckBox just appears in the ContentPane instead of the tab for it.

Comment: Well, just use a dom inspector to figure out what node you shoud use as the first argument of the placeAt method !!! titleNode instead of domNode maybe ?

Comment: Jeez, no need to shout. This is what ended up working: `cb.placeAt('report_tab_container_tablist_dijit_layout_ContentPane_'+ i.toString(), "first");`